# Can someone explain this simple Haskell code to me in detail

Tags: haskell

I found this on a really old post and did not want to ask there because it might never get answered.

```
f xs = maximum . filter (< maximum xs) $ xs
```

It looks to me like it is

- taking the maximum of a filtered list
- that is less than the maximum of the list

​

```
secondLargest :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a
secondLargest [] = error "Empty List"
secondLargest [x] = error "Empty List"
secondLargest xs
    | ((maximum . filter (< maximum xs) $ xs) >= (maximum xs)) = maximum xs
    | otherwise = (maximum . filter (< maximum xs) $ xs)
```

the code above is what I am working with now. Basically I am unable to sort the list and the code above finds the second largest element as long as the largest and the second largest are not the same.

would anyone be able to help shed some light?

Comment: basically I am trying to find the second largest number in a list and finding this I do not understand what it is doing.

Comment: It'll return the second biggest element of a list. For example, given `[1,2,3,4,5]` it will return `4`.

Comment: I posted the new code I have now but it does not work with things that have duplicates.

Comment: "Unable to sort" and unwilling to use an import. Huh. I guess this is homework, then? You should probably try to find a way to do it yourself. Tip: you can calculate the `n-1`th order statistic in a single pass over the list. I challenge you to do so. An extra challenge: write it as a fold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really simple:

```hs
f xs = maximum . filter (< maximum xs) $ xs
```

Let's suppose `xs = [1,2,3,4,5]`. Hence, `maximum xs = 5`. Thus, we have:

```hs
f [1,2,3,4,5] = maximum . filter (< 5) $ [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Next, we filter out all the elements less than `5`. Hence we get:

```hs
f [1,2,3,4,5] = maximum $ [1,2,3,4] -- notice that 5 is no more in the list
```

Finally, we get the maximum of the remaining elements:

```hs
f [1,2,3,4,5] = 4
```

This happens to be the second largest element of the original list.

Comment: Perfect explanation for me. Thank you very much

Comment: what would happen lets say if the list was [1,2,3,4,5,5], the second 5 should be the second largest in the list but since it filters everything less than 5 it would be missed.

Comment: and if you changed the < to <= it would then not work in the first situation where the list is [1,2,3,4,5] as it would return 5

Comment: It always finds the second largest element in the list. In the list `[1,2,3,4,5,5]` the second largest element is `4` and not `5`. It doesn't matter whether you have just one `5` or a million, the second largest element is always `4`.

Comment: @Juscallmesteve It still works if you think of "second largest" as speaking about the mathematical ordering of integers, i.e. 4 is still the second-largest integer in the list as the two 5s are the same integer. If you want to account for duplicates, perhaps you should sort the list from largest to smallest and take the second element (if it exists).

Comment: would it be possible to do something like     if maximum xs = f xs, then remove that one instance of the max and then just return the max of the new list?

Comment: @Juscallmesteve See my answer regarding that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to account for duplicates as you've asked in the comments, you can use `Data.List.delete` instead of `filter` to remove the largest element. This will only remove a single instance of it:

```
import Data.List (delete)

f xs = maximum . delete (maximum xs) $ xs
```

This yields:

```
λ. f [1,2,3,4,5]
4
λ. f [1,2,3,4,5,5]
5
```

Of course, this only works for lists of length 2 or longer. If you want to account for all cases so the function is total, you can do something like this:

```
f xs | length xs >= 2 = maximum . delete (maximum xs) $ xs
     | null xs        = 0   -- default case when the list is empty
     | otherwise      = maximum xs
```

To do it without the import, you can implement `delete` by hand:

```
delete :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
delete x [] = []
delete x (y:ys) | x == y    = ys
                | otherwise = y : delete x ys
```

Comment: I am not able to use import in the program. Other than that your program is flawless

Comment: Any idea how to go about this without using an import?

Answer (score 1):

It finds the second largest number from a array `xs`, to break it down.

```
let xs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let a = filter (< maximum xs) xs
-- a is an array of all elements from 'xs' except of the max elem of 'xs'
-- which is [1, 2, 3]

let b = maximum (a) -- gets the largest elem of a
--  b is th largest element of 'a'
-- which is 3
```

and applying `maximum` on that gives the second largest `elem`.